# gopass doesn't syncing with repository

Tags: passwords, password-management, ubuntu-18.04

I've installed [gopass](https://github.com/gopasspw/gopass) on Ubuntu 18.04 host, everything is working fine except one thing.

When I run syncing command:

```
$ gopass sync                                                        
Sync starting ...
[<root>]
   WARNING: Mount uses RCS backend 'noop'. Not syncing!
All done
```

I didn't encountered such problem on Mac OS, what might be a problem here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If in `cat ~/.config/gopass/config.yml` you see lines like:

```
path: gpgcli-noop-fs+file:///home/xxxxx/.password-store-xxx-xxx
```

try to replace `noop` with `gitcli`.